# Facebook SDK takes over "$" from jQuery - how to stop that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm using both the Facebook SDK and jQuery... for some reason, with the Facebook SDK loading, `$` no longer works as the jQuery object. All my jQuery calls still work but I have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`... see below for an example. I also have other code in my footer that is just jQuery stuff and the `$` doesn't work there either. **Everything functions perfectly but I hate this and want to be able to use `$` as a shortcut for jQuery!** How can I get my `$` back?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://x.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({  // (this code straight from FB developer docs)
        appId: '1234123412341234',
        channelUrl: '//mysite.com/channel.html',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

    function checkLoginStatus(response) {
        if(response && response.status == 'connected') {
            jQuery('#login-btn').hide();
            jQuery('#logout-btn').show();
            console.log('User ID: ' + response.authResponse.userID);
        } else {
            jQuery('#login-btn').show();
            jQuery('#logout-btn').hide();
        }
    }

// Load the SDK asynchronously (this code straight from FB developer docs)
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk',
        ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
</script>
```

Comment: I searched the entire source code and facebook SDK definitely **does not** use the variable `$` even locally.

Comment: I hear ya-- I'm surprised too because I can't find anything in the docs about possible conflict with jQuery. I'm going to go ahead and try cutting some other JS bits in my code to see if I can identify the culprit. Regardless, for right now, this question stands and I got a great answer. Thank you for your comment and for taking the time to peek at the FB SDK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a self-executing function, and pass `jQuery` as argument `$`.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
    FB.init({  // (this code straight from FB developer docs)
        appId: '1234123412341234',
        channelUrl: '//mysite.com/channel.html',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

    function checkLoginStatus(response) {
        if(response && response.status == 'connected') {

            $('#login-btn').hide();
            $('#logout-btn').show();

            console.log('User ID: ' + response.authResponse.userID);

        } else {

            $('#login-btn').show();
            $('#logout-btn').hide();

        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You can read more [here](http://codetunnel.com/blog/post/using-selfexecuting-functions-to-preserve-dollar-sign-compatibility-in-jquery)

Comment: This is my preferred approach. Additionally, RequireJS (or similar) can be employed for a similar sort of "dependency injection".

Answer (score 0):

only one library can use $.  so you'll need to assign either jQuery or the FB API to something else.  For example you could do this.

```
window._ = window.jQuery
```

there's also **http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/**

Comment: Use `jQuery.noConflict` for (additional) alias assignments. It will also remove any jQuery clobbering, should it exist. However, `_` is commonly used for underscore.js ..